# How to know if the user is on top of my Activity?

Tags: android

I´m trying to work with Swiperefreshlayout, it works perfect, but I need to know when the user is on the top of my Activity. I was reading about this, I found a method called "setOnScrollListener", but I think is just for a ListView. I don´t use a ListView, I´m using a RelativeLayout, inside it, I put cards layouts.

My XML structure is this:

- Swiperefreshlayout

  - DrawerLayout

    - RelativeLayout

      - ScrollView

        - Cards with different data

I have tried to catch the ScrollView, but it doesn´t have the setOnScrollListener.

I can´t change to a ListView (the Activity was created by a partner). I must use cards view...

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subclass `Swiperefreshlayout` and override `canChildScrollUp`. Retrieve the `ScrollView`, and `return scrollViewInstance.getScrollY() > 0;`. Don't forget to use your subclass of `Swiperefreshlayout` in the layout

Comment: I did it, I have all well, but... Don´t I need a listener? Where call the method?

Comment: the method is called by the system, you don't have to call it manually. If it is not working post the code you are using

Comment: Mmmm, I don´t know how to make a relationship between the SwipeRefreshLayout and my subclass... I have this: http://pastebin.com/Jjqh6h5J

Comment: I found a easier method:  scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY(); 
                if(scrollY == 0) swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
                else swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);

            }
});

Comment: You should really look into the sub class method.

Answer (score 1):

i think i suggest you can use the viewflipper in android.it can easily represent the different layout.example:

```
flippy.setDisplayedChild(flippy.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.Swiperefreshlayout)));
flippy.setDisplayedChild(flippy.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout)));
```